# Visual Studio 2008 C++ thread window's priority column

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

Visual C++ 2008's Debug-->Window-->Threads is showing a thread with -8 in the priority column.  Its obviously a worker thread within some library that I shouldn't *need* to know about.  So consider this question limited to the priority level.

Studying the definitions in `WinBase.h` around `THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL` doesn't show what -8 would be. MSFT's page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx seems to show that values of -2 to -7 for `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`, otherwise -1, -2, or -15 are the only legal negative values.

So I'm curious what this -8 might mean?

Comment: Keep in mind that these identifiers are *offsets*, added to the priority class of the process and the thread.  This thread was probably started by a system component that uses the native api, underlying call is NtSetInformationThread().  Which takes any *absolute* value between 1 and 31.

Comment: So I've been downvoted for "not doing any research," despite reading the header and manpages and checking stack overflow itself as well as googling?  Fair enough.  I admit I don't know what the good resources are for this type of question.  What source should I have consulted?

Comment: Meh, wasn't me but I'd assume a reader thought that an answer to this question just would not make you do anything differently.  Very hard to imagine you would.  Use the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to find out what kind of questions are welcome here, "there is no actual problem to be solved" is the 3rd bullet.

Comment: With respect, the third bullet you site is in the context of subjective questions.  I don't think my question is at all subjective, so I don't think that bullet applies.